# Chrome Extension: "These extensions can see and change information on this site"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Brave/Chrome and when I click the puzzle icon in the top right corner next to the row of pinned extensions, my extension is separated from the rest at the top with the label "These extensions can see and change information on this site". I'm not sure why. Here is my `manifest.json`.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Extension Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {
        "512": "src/logo.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Extension Name",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "src/bg.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["src/content.js"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["src/popup2.html", "src/script2.js"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ]
}
```

My only permission is for `storage`. How do I make my extension not be labeled as having access to "see and change information on this site"?

Comment: I have never seen such behavior when pinning an extension.
The message should lawfully appear at installation time

Comment: Your extension has host permissions for all sites through content scripts' `matches`.

Comment: @wOxxOm so it's `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`? Ok that makes sense. That's the answer. And actually now I'm seeing a lot of other extensions I use have the same label - not sure why I didn't see those when I wrote the question.